# Problems with safari nav bar in PWA application

Tags: html, css, progressive-web-apps

I'm having some problems to deal with notches and navbar spacing of PWA application in IOS devices.

For example, i have a chat input that has a position absolute with `bottom: 0` and it doesn't appear on Safari because of the navbar height.

Refer to the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

This are the rules of the chat input:

```
.event-chat-input {
    height: $event-chat-input-height;
    box-shadow: $box-shadow-default;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

I know that are some variables that deal with the notches insets, such as: 

`safe-area-inset-top
safe-area-inset-right
safe-area-inset-left
safe-area-inset-bottom`

But it didn't work either and also wouldn't change a lot in this case because what is causing the most part of the bug is the navbar safari and not the iPhone X notch

Did you guys experience the same problem? What would be the best approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get around this is to attempt to force Safari's nav to always show. This way positioning won't be determined by the changing viewport size.

```
/* Allows content to fill the viewport and go beyond the bottom */
height: 100%;

/* Allows you to scroll below the viewport; default value is visible */
overflow-y: scroll;

/* To smooth any scrolling behavior */
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

That may or may not work.

Comment: But the input chat has an absolute positioning